# A cryptography web application works well locally but don't on the cloud

Tags: java, cryptography, wso2

I made a cryptography web application and tried it locally and it works well. But when i tried it on WSO2 cloud it gives this exception report:

```
HTTP Status 500 - PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

message PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
Only a type can be imported. javax.crypto.BadPaddingException resolves to a package

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
Only a type can be imported. javax.crypto.Cipher resolves to a package

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
Only a type can be imported. javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException resolves to a package

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
Only a type can be imported. javax.crypto.KeyGenerator resolves to a package

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
Only a type can be imported. javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException resolves to a package

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
Only a type can be imported. javax.crypto.SecretKey resolves to a package

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
Only a type can be imported. javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec resolves to a package

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 21 in the jsp file: /Certificate_student.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
Cipher cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 138 in the jsp file: /Certificate_student.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
SecretKeySpec cannot be resolved to a type
```

and other errors, please how to solve those exceptions ?

This is my header

```
<%@page import="org.apache.catalina.tribes.util.Arrays"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@include file="connection.jsp"%>
<%@page import="java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException" %>
<%@page import="java.security.InvalidKeyException" %>
<%@page import="java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException" %>
<%@page import="javax.crypto.BadPaddingException" %>
<%@page import="javax.crypto.Cipher" %>
<%@page import="javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException" %>
<%@page import="javax.crypto.KeyGenerator" %>
<%@page import="javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException" %>
<%@page import="javax.crypto.SecretKey" %>
<%@page import="javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec"%>
```

Comment: Personally I think there is something terribly wrong at your cloud service provider. Maybe the use of `javax.crypto` is somehow prohibited. Do you have details on what cloud framework/provider you are using?

Comment: Are you sure the jars with the `crypto` package are available for your server? I mean, in that case I would expect a `ClassNotFoundException` instead of the errors you find, but I can think of few legitimate reasons for the error you are getting.

Comment: There is something decidedly smelly about importing crypto libraries in a JSP.

Comment: I'm using WSO2 cloud  https://cloud.wso2.com/

Comment: That's a terrible website, you can only read the terms of service and it doesn't even load fully. Must be a black cloud provider or something. Boris has a point, normally *if* you do crypto, you should not do it at the front end.

Comment: What kind of jvm is provided by your Clood provider? Oracle, open, ...?

Comment: if this cloud server is short-handed in capabilities, what is other one can support crypto libraries?

Comment: Hannes i don't know the kind of jvm it uses. @owlstead excuse me "you should not do it at the front end" How can i do it?

Comment: JSP should generally be used only for displaying your site, not for doing the actual work. The actual cryptography should be done by classes you write for this purpose, and the JSP should just provide the data for the objects of those classes and the display the results from calling their methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runtime of [WSO2 App Cloud](http://cloud.wso2.com) is powered by WSO2 App Server. This issues was due to a class loading issues in the WSO2 App Server. We at WSO2 have fixed this issue and you should be able to try your code successfully now.

BTW, next time when you want to tag WSO2 Cloud in a question, use the wso2cloud tag. It will help us to answer your questions quickly.